# Android Navigation Drawer Selector Color

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to change the highlight color on the Navigation Drawer Fragment. I have used the pre-built project template for the navigation drawer. I have searched this site for many different solutions but so far none of them have worked. Currently, this is what I have:

**list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/ListBackground" android:state_activated="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/OrangeBackground" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/OrangeBackground" android:state_activated="true"></item>
</selector>
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**
I only am posting the relevant mDrawerList constructor/decleration.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
                view.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                        getString(R.string.title_section4),
                        getString(R.string.title_section5),
                        getString(R.string.title_section6)
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change item position,like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/OrangeBackground" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/OrangeBackground" android:state_activated="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/ListBackground"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did make it so that when I click a menu item it temporarily changes color. However, that color does not stay.

Comment: you need to add 
        android:listSelector="@android:color/black" to your listView xml

Comment: Ok I tried adding that to my fragment_navigation_drawer.xml but it didn't change anything.

Comment: you have listview in your drawer?if yes put that line in ListView tag

Comment: if you don't have listview tag get listview from drawer and set above line for it

Comment: My listview is the drawer fragment yes.